# printing vector of list std::vector<std::list<unsigned>>

Tags: c++

FIXED:
I had the wrong declaration in the header file. After I fixed the declaration I was able to build and print it.

---

I am trying to print vector of lists and I get the following error when I try to build in this 3 ways. where I am wrong? Looking into other post number 2, 3 was sugested for C++11 or newer, while number 1 is classic version. ( [how do i print a vector of arrays/lists using int iterator in cpp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48478863/how-do-i-print-a-vector-of-arrays-lists-using-int-iterator-in-cpp/48478963) )
I also tried using i.begin() instead of (*i).begin() for the list or vec[i].begin(), but I get other types of errors.

I am not sure which C++ version I have.

Another reference (http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/75091/).

Nothing is working.
The functions are declared in a .hpp file

```
[ 10%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/a.out.gtest.dir/app/proj1.cpp.o
[ 20%] Linking CXX executable bin/a.out.gtest
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/a.out.gtest.dir/app/proj1.cpp.o: in function `phaseTwo(std::__1::vector<std::__1::list<unsigned int, std::__1::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::list<unsigned int, std::__1::allocator<unsigned int> > > >&, unsigned int)':
/home/compsci161/projects/proj1/app/proj1.cpp:43: undefined reference to `printVec(std::__1::vector<std::__1::list<unsigned int, std::__1::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::list<unsigned int, std::__1::allocator<unsigned int> > > > const&)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/a.out.gtest.dir/build.make:114: bin/a.out.gtest] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:80: CMakeFiles/a.out.gtest.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

Here is my code. I tried different variations.
number 1

```
int main(){

std::vector<std::list<unsigned>> vec = { 
            {1, 3, 5, 55, }, 
            {9, 20, 41, 75, }, 
            {44, 205, 453, 567, }, 
            {55, 245, 567, 890, }, 
            {100, 234, 456, 678, }, 
        };
}
void phaseTwo(std::vector<std::list<unsigned>> & vec, unsigned f)
{
    printVec(vec);

}
printVec(vec);
}

void printVec(std::vector<std::list<unsigned>>  vec)
{
    for(std::vector<std::list<int>>::iterator i = vec.begin(); i !=vec.end(); i++)  
    {
        for(std::list<int>::iterator iterList = (*i).begin(); iterList != (*i).end(); iterList++)   
        {
            std::cout << *iterList << ", ";        
        }   
        std::cout << "\n ";   
    }
}
```

number 2

```
void printVec(std::vector<std::list<unsigned>>  vec)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
       for (auto e: vec[i]) {
            std::cout << e << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n ";  
    }
}
```

number 3

```
void printVec(std::vector<std::list<unsigned>>  vec)
{
    for (auto i: vec) {
        for (auto e: i) {
            std::cout << e << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n ";  
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to include the function declaration, which does not match any of your definitions, in the question.

Comment: BTW: cplusplus.com is not worth what you're paying for it.

Comment: the error message you posted is for an error in a function called `phaseTwo`. Please post a [mcve] and the corresponding error message. You need not post more code, but we cannot help you to fix that error when the code you show is causing a different error

Comment: Put your main at the end of your file. or add declaration before usage.

Comment: BTW, some (const) references should be added to avoid extra copies.

Comment: Sorry, I should have written this down. The declarations of the functions are in a .hpp file. I am calling the print function from PhaseTwo() function.

Answer (score 0):

You first problem:

```
/home/compsci161/projects/proj1/app/proj1.cpp:43: undefined reference to `printVec(std::__1::vector<std::__1::list<unsigned int, std::__1::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::list<unsigned int, std::__1::allocator<unsigned int> > > > const&)'
```

The important big `undefined reference to printVec`.

Is because at the point where you call the function the compiler has not seen a declaration that such a function exists.

```
            {100, 234, 456, 678, }, 
        };
printVec(vec);   // At this point.
                 // This is the first time the compiler has seen
                 // the function: printVec
}
```

Solve this be forward declaring the function. OR move the `main()` to the bottomo of the program so it is written after the `printVec()` function.

---

Another Issue:

You are passing `std::vector<std::list<unsigned>>` to the function.

But if you look closely you are getting an iterator for:

```
 std::vector<std::list<int>>  // Notice int is not unsigned.
```

Here:

```
 for(std::vector<std::list<int>>::iterator i
                         ^^^^^^^^

 // and

 for(std::list<int>::iterator
             ^^^^^^^
```

---

Why not use version 3. It is designed to solve this exact problem.

Other ways are to use type alias to represent the types. That way if you change the type in one place it automatically changes in all places that it is used.

```
using ListOfData       = std::list<unsigned>;
using VectorOfDataList = std::vector<ListOfData>;

void printVec(VectorOfDataList  vec) {
    // STUFF
}
```

Now if you change the type of the underlying data from `unsigned` to `int` you only change it in one place and all locations (that use `VectorOfDataList` will automatically be changed to use the new underlying type.

A basic "Code Smell" is caused by needing to touch the code in multiple places because of one change. You should be able to change the thing in preferably one place and this change will affect all usage points.

---

An issue with your loop.
You are always using values (thus causing copies to be made).

```
void printVec(std::vector<std::list<unsigned>>  vec)
{
    for (auto i: vec) {
         //   ^^^^^   here i is a value.
         //           i.e. not a reference. So you are making
         //           a copy of the list into i.
        for (auto e: i) {
            std::cout << e << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n ";  
    }
}
```

I would write like this:

```
void printVec(std::vector<std::list<unsigned>>  vec)
{
    for (auto const& i: vec) {       // Notice the const&
        for (auto const& e: i) {     // Notice the const& (not strictly required
                                     // but makes using the for loop consistent.
            std::cout << e << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n ";  
    }
}
```

---

As a side note.

You realize you are passing the vector by value. As such a copy is made of the whole vector (and all contained list).

```
// Pass by value.
void printVec(std::vector<std::list<unsigned>>  vec)


// Pass by const reference.
void printVec(std::vector<std::list<unsigned>> const& vec)
// Because it is a reference the compiler does not need to make a copy.
```

Comment: I actually found that I have const in my declaration.

Comment: I did not have the right declaration. After, fixing that I was able to run it.  Thank you!

Comment: @Slavy Noted a couple of other things that will make your code better.

Comment: That is great detailed explanation. Now, I understand it even better. Thank you so much!